# Why does my pregnant cat chew boxes and is it harmful for the kittens?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, chewing

My cat, Yoda, is pregnant. She started to chew, particularly on boxes where she might think it's a safe place to give birth.

So, I was just wondering, would the chewing affect her kittens in her belly?

Furthermore, I am pretty sure she's not having a PICA (the eating disorder) because she started to do it when she was in pregnant (second time). The first time she was pregnant, she did not chew the boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Cats like cardboard boxes for many reasons. They're fun to hide in, they block drafts, they're defensible (sometimes), and cardboard can be good for sharpening claws and cleaning teeth. Some cats just like puncturing cardboard and paper. Maybe sinking fangs into paper is for them what popping bubble wrap is for us...

In other words, I wouldn't worry about it. It isn't likely to be a problem unless she damages something you need. (A friend of mine once had to explain to a professor that the cat had chewed up her homework...)

Answer (score 2):

Chewing is fine but excessive eating may be harmful if there are glues/dyes in the cardboard.

The behavior could indicate a number of things:

1. Hunger.
2. Tooth irritation.
3. Having fun.
4. Sensing a pleasant taste.
5. Being bored.

The pregnancy is going to temporarily change her mood/psyche a little and as a result there may be more or less of the above items.